# Basic Hash Table with Chaining

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am preparing for some interviews coming up so I am re-writing a basic hash table with chaining from scratch. I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
hashTable was 0x1110116.
```

At this line:

```
auto entry = hashTable[hashValue];
```

in the insert function. I checked and re-checked my code but I do not see what the problem is. Here is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>

const int size = 128;

struct Node {
    int key;
    int value;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node(const int& x, const int& y, Node* next = nullptr) : 
        key(x),
        value(y),
        next(next) {}
};
Node** hashTable = nullptr;


void print() {
    Node* temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp = hashTable[i];
        std::cout << "Key: " << temp->key << " Value: " << temp->value << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int hash(int key) { return key % size; }

void insert(int key, int value) {
    int hashValue = hash(key);
    Node* previous = nullptr;
    auto entry = hashTable[hashValue];

    while (entry != nullptr) {
        previous = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    if (entry == nullptr) {
        entry = new Node(key, value);
        if (previous = nullptr) {
            hashTable[hashValue] = entry;
        }
        else {
            previous->next = entry;
        }
    }
    else {
        entry->value = value;
    }
}

void remove(int key) {
    int hashValue = hash(key);
    Node* previous = nullptr;
    auto entry = hashTable[hashValue];

    while (entry != nullptr && entry->key != key) {
        previous = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    if (entry == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Key not found" << "\n";
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (previous == nullptr) {
            hashTable[hashValue] = entry->next;
        }
        else {
            previous->next = entry->next;
        }
        delete entry;
    }
}

void search(int key) {
    bool flag = false;
    int hashValue = hash(key);
    auto entry = hashTable[hashValue];

    while (entry != nullptr) {
        if (entry->key == key) {
            std::cout << entry->value << " ";
            flag = true;
        }
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    if (!flag) std::cout << "No key found" << "\n";
}


int main() {

    insert(1, 1);
    insert(2, 2);
    insert(3, 3);
    insert(4, 4);
    print();

    remove(2);
    print();

    search(3);


}
```

Comment: Where is the hashTable given some memory like Node*hashTable[128]?

Comment: My compiler has a hint:  test.cpp:41:22: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        if (previous = nullptr) {

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Nice did spot that but still same issue as I stated above.

Comment: @MatthewFisher I am not sure if I understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code used hashTable without allocating any space for its contents.  This is undefined behavior and will crash for sure.  I just made is an array of pointers of length 'size'.  You also could use new or better yet use a vector.

The compiler also warned of using = when == was intended.

The print() function would print nullptr causing a crash.  I added a check.

You almost had it!

```
#include <iostream>

const int size = 128;

struct Node {
    int key;
    int value;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node(const int& x, const int& y, Node* next = nullptr) : 
        key(x),
        value(y),
        next(next) {}
};
Node* hashTable[size]; // give the hash table some space


void print() {
    Node* temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp = hashTable[i];
        if(temp) // don't try to print of temp == nullptr
            std::cout << "Key: " << temp->key << " Value: " << temp->value << " " << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int hash(int key) { return key % size; }

void insert(int key, int value) {
    int hashValue = hash(key);
    Node* previous = nullptr;
    auto entry = hashTable[hashValue];

    while (entry != nullptr) {
        previous = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    if (entry == nullptr) {
        entry = new Node(key, value);
        if (previous == nullptr) {
            hashTable[hashValue] = entry;
        }
        else {
            previous->next = entry;
        }
    }
    else {
        entry->value = value;
    }
}

void remove(int key) {
    int hashValue = hash(key);
    Node* previous = nullptr;
    auto entry = hashTable[hashValue];

    while (entry != nullptr && entry->key != key) {
        previous = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    if (entry == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Key not found" << "\n";
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (previous == nullptr) {
            hashTable[hashValue] = entry->next;
        }
        else {
            previous->next = entry->next;
        }
        delete entry;
    }
}

void search(int key) {
    bool flag = false;
    int hashValue = hash(key);
    auto entry = hashTable[hashValue];

    while (entry != nullptr) {
        if (entry->key == key) {
            std::cout << entry->value << " ";
            flag = true;
        }
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    if (!flag) std::cout << "No key found" << "\n";
}


int main() {

    insert(1, 1);
    insert(2, 2);
    insert(3, 3);
    insert(4, 4);
    print();

    remove(2);
    print();

    search(3);


}
```

Comment: "This is undefined behavior and will crash for sure."  -- unless it decides not to crash, undefined behavior will do as it pleases :)

Comment: I'm not aware of a system where the 0 memory address is in writable user space.  It is possible of course.

Comment: Amiga/AmigaDOS, for one, would let you freely read or write anywhere (as would any embedded environments that do not have an MMU present to guard memory accesses)

Comment: Amiga? You must be as old as I am, lol.  Good point on the embedded platforms.